# Adal Angular 4 cannot authenticate to dynamic 365 CRM

Tags: angular, adal, adal.js

I am using 'adal-angular4' library to authenticate to dynamic 365 CRM online.

- I set up azure application according to https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp.
- My code for authentication is almost the same as on example  https://github.com/benbaran/adal-angular4-example.
- My home component model:

  ```
  config: any = {
   tenant: '',
   clientId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  };

  constructor(private adalService: Adal4Service) {
      this.adalService.init(this.config);        

      this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();

      // Check if the user is authenticated. If not, call the login() method
      if (!this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated) {
          this.adalService.login();
      }       

      console.log('token: ' + this.service.userInfo.token);
  }
  ```

Here I successfully get token and all user info.

But when I tried to acquire/verify my token for dynamic 365 CRM I always get error:

```
"Token renewal operation failed due to timeout"
```

My code for acquiring token:

```
  this.adalService.acquireToken('https://comdynamics365en.crm4.dynamics.com')
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data); // never get this
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Error while AcquireToken. Error Info: " + error);
        })
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Never ever provide private keys from azure here. Are you providing the tenant?

Comment: No i did not provide tenant I thought it is not obligatory.

Comment: I set up "Multi-tenanted" option to "No", it means only one tenant. I do not need to specify tenant, if I understand it well.

Comment: I'm following the same example code using a single tenant and get the same problem. I can authenticate to azure AD fine but trying to access a linked API with acquireToken gives me "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout" :(

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout" by changing this.adalService.acquireToken('https://comdynamics365en.crm4.dynamics.com')

to

this.adalService.acquireToken('{application ID }') (the application ID is listed in Azure, no idea why the ID works and the URI doesn't)

Hope this helps

Comment: The  procedure of login is to get azure token first when you login and after it you acquire CRM token with the azure token. Your example really retrieve token when you call this.adalService.acquireToken(application ID), but this token is the same as azure already retrieve and I cannot authorize in CRM with that token. I need token according to my CRM organization, by URL.